# lapply(makeCacheMatrix(a),solveCache) does not work fine

Tags: r, lapply

I am facing a strange issue. Could someone help where I am going wrong.
I am a noob at R. What I have known about lapply is it applies a function over a list.

Now, when I do this,

```
lapply(makeCacheMatrix(a),solveCache)
```

it gives an error

> Error in x$getInverse : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable'

However when I do,

```
m1<-makeCacheMatrix(a)
solveCache(m1)
```

It gives me correct response without an error.

m1<- is indeed a list which I checked through mode(m1). So ideally lapply should work.

Could someone please help me out why `lapply(makeCacheMatrix(a),solveCache)` gives the error...I mean either I capture output of `makeCacheMatrix(a)` and pass it to lapply or I pass it directly, it should work in both the cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`lapply(X, FUN, ...)` applies the function `FUN` over each *element* of the list `X`. It appears the `solveCache` function operates on the list as a whole, not just a single element of the list.